# Как описать уже объявленный класс

Tags: typescript

```
import { Command } from '@adonisjs/ace';
import * as Adonis from "@adonis-types/ace";


export class MakeTsController extends Command  {

    get signature() {
        return 'make:ts:controller'
    }

    get description() {
        return 'Tell something helpful about this command'
    }

    async handle(): Promise<any> {
        this.info('Dummy implementation for make:ts:controller command')
    }
}
```

Класс Command не имеет описания, это просто класс на js.
Как установить тип класса для Command: Adonis.Command?

Comment: никак, переопределяйте его в Command, а не в типе который его расширяет.

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics